# Creating a stacked bar chart with dates, hours, and activity

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to create a stacked bar chart (or anything that may represent the data better).
I have a list with dates, hours worked, and activities.

How can i make a chart that looks like this?

[image]

My data looks like this:

[image]

So far selecting all fields does not give me any options to do anything similar, it either groups all hours under one activity or date.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried creating a stacked bar chart and used your sheet data as seen below, but unfortunately, I'm also unable to get the result that you wanted just by relying to your current sheet data format.

[image]

**RECOMMENDATION:**

With that being said, I have tweaked your sheet format as seen below:

[image]

I've changed the columns of **Hours** and **Activity** into **Task 1** and **Task 2** columns and put the hours on these tasks, since these are just 2 tasks and the only dynamic data are the **Hours** per **Date**. This is the only successful method that I've tried to achieve your desired Stacked bar chart format using your raw sheet data.

**RESULT:**

[image]

**Additional tweaks on the Chart Editor:**

Checked "Aggregate" on the **Date**.

[image]

Renamed the **Vertical axis title** to "Hours"

[image]